I receiving RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED while launching my flutter app
E/GeneratedPluginRegistrant(14556): Error registering plugin share_plus, dev.fluttercommunity.plus.share.SharePlusPlugin
E/GeneratedPluginRegistrant(14556): java.lang.SecurityException: com.namp.zeon: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
while starting the app this exception thrown.
dependencies:
font_awesome_flutter: ^10.3.0
google_fonts: ^5.1.0
provider: ^6.0.5
get: ^4.6.5
http: ^1.1.0
shared_preferences: ^2.1.1
flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
geolocator: ^9.0.2
auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
flutter_typeahead: ^4.8.0
screenshot: ^2.1.0
qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
intl: ^0.18.0
geocoding: ^2.0.5
url_launcher: ^6.1.10
overlay_support: ^2.1.0
path_provider: ^2.0.13
share_extend: ^2.0.0
flutter_secure_storage: ^8.0.0
permission_handler: ^11.0.1
intl_phone_field: ^3.1.0
avatar_view: ^1.0.1
webview_flutter: ^4.2.2
share_plus: ^4.5.3
flutter_screenutil: ^5.9.0
responsive_framework: ^1.1.0
email_validator: ^2.1.17
decimal: ^2.3.3
custom_date_range_picker: ^1.0.10
string_extensions: ^0.6.12
syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^22.1.38
table_calendar: ^3.0.9
paytm_allinonesdk: ^1.2.6
awesome_snackbar_content: ^0.1.3
syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^22.2.5
fl_country_code_picker: ^0.0.4
country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
firebase_core: ^2.15.1
firebase_messaging: ^14.6.6
in_app_review: ^2.0.9
flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.4
google_maps_flutter: ^2.6.1
google_map_polyline_new: ^0.3.0+2
rxdart: ^0.27.7
timezone: ^0.9.2
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
rename: ^2.1.1
sms_autofill: ^2.4.0
lottie: ^2.6.0
flutter_animarker: ^3.2.0
get_upi: ^0.0.4
custom_map_markers: ^0.0.2+1
fluttertoast: ^8.2.2
gif_view: ^0.4.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.4
hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
device_preview: ^1.1.0
smooth_page_indicator: ^1.1.0
connectivity_plus: ^5.0.2
ns_upi: ^1.0.2
sqflite: ^2.3.0
flutter_image_compress: ^2.1.0
upgrader: ^9.0.0
package_info_plus: ^4.2.0
open_file: ^3.3.2
ffi: ^2.0.1
easy_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.7
app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.5
razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.7
simple_pip_mode: ^0.8.0
dart_ping: ^9.0.1
flutter_in_app_pip: ^1.7.3
visibility_detector: ^0.4.0+2
scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.3.8
flutter_flavor: ^3.1.3
live_activities: ^1.9.3
device_info_plus: ^9.1.2
jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
tuple: ^2.0.2
firebase_analytics: ^10.7.4
sentry_flutter: ^8.9.0
amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2: ^3.6.5
dependency_overrides:
ffi: ^1.0.0
package_info_plus: ^4.2.0


try to upgrade latest share_plus: ^10.0.2 version

From Android 14 (SDK 34), it's compulsory to define the RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED when registering Broadcast Receivers, here issue seems to be from share_plus dependency, but you are using a ver old version.
You can try upgrading it to the latest version, it should be fixed.
https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/install

My flutter version allow me to upgrade only upto share_plus: ^4.5.3
